# How to create list of photos in SQL Server database in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, web, file-upload

I have code to create an image (string) in the database, but I want to register a list of strings. That is: a few photos. But there is a problem.

Business entity model

```
public class Product
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public List<string> images { get; set; } = new List<string>();
}
```

View model

```
public class product
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public List<IFormFile> images { get; set; } =newList<IFormFile();
}

public class Uploadfile
{
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _webHostEnvironment;

    public Uploadfile (IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment)
    {
        _webHostEnvironment = webHostEnvironment;
    }

    public string upload(IFormFile file)
    {
        if (file == null)  
             return "";

        var path = _webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath + "\\img\\" + file.FileName;
        using var f = System.IO.File.Create(path);
        file.CopyTo(f);
        return file.FileName;  
    }
```

Controller

```
    private  IWebHostEnvironment Environment;

    public ProductController(IWebHostEnvironment _environment)
    {
        Environment = _environment;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public void create(Models.product product)
    {
        blproduct blp = new blproduct();
        BE.Product pr = new Product();
        pr.grouping = product.grouping;
        Uploadfile uf = new Uploadfile(Environment);
        pr.images = uf.upload(product.images);//Error => (product.images)
          blp.create(pr);
    }
```

This code works to create the image in the database, but when I define the image property as a list, it doesn't work.

Comment: product.images -> product is a Models.product, not a Product.

Comment: Could you share your code of  view? What's your file?

Answer (score 0):

You have method

```
public string upload(IFormFile file)
```

but instead of parameter `IFormFile` you're put `List<string>`